# Change the state of an image with javasript and html

Tags: javascript, html

Please can i get a help about this javaScript code and html below, am try the change the state of the lightbulb with javascript such that when i click on the turn on button, the bulb will change to yellow and when i click on the turn off button, the bulb will change to white, i don't actually no what i did wrong.

```
function turnOn() {
      let changeState = document.querySelector('.img');
      changeState.src = "lightbulb.png";
      changeState.style.color = "yellow";
}

function turnOff() {
    let turnOff = document.querySelector('.img');
     turnOff.src = "lightbulb.png";
     turnOff.style.color = 'white';
}


<button class="turn-on" onclick="turnOn();">Turn On</button>
<img  src="lightbulb.png" alt="" width="200" class="img">
<button class="turn-off" onclick="turnOff();">Turn Off</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the color of a lightbulb in an image with `style.color`.

Create two seperate images - one for "on", one for "off" and then modify the `changeState.src` lines to point to the correct files.

You can remove the `style.color`lines.

That should work.

PS: You can programmatically change a state of images if they are saved as [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) images, but that's usually more complicated than just creating two images.

Comment: Another option would be to use a CSS filter on an image, and swap a class on the IMG element.